# How to correctly load columns of dates and times from an excel file?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I'm trying to read an `excel` file as a dataframe; for this purpose I used two different methods:

```
library(xlsx)
df = read.xlsx("file.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1)
library("readxl")
my_data <- read_excel("file.xlsx")
```

File `file.xlsx` has several columns, in particular two of them contain dates and times. For example:

[image]

for dates, and

[image]

for times. These results are not read correctly from the above lines of code:

```
> df$Date.pub
 [1] 44293                          44293                         
 [3] 44294                          44294                         
 [5] 44295                          44295                         
 [7] 44295                          44300                         
 [9] 44300                          44300                         
 [11] 44279                                              24/03/2021
 [13] 44295                          44295                         
 [15] 44300                          44300                         
 [17] 44300                          44300                         
 [19] 44300                          44300                         
 [21] 44300                          44300                         
 Levels:                     24/03/2021 44279 44293 44294 44295 44300
> my_data$`Date.pub`
 [1] "44293"      "44293"      "44294"      "44294"      "44295"      "44295"     
 [7] "44295"      "44300"      "44300"      "44300"      "44279"      "24/03/2021"
 [13] "44295"      "44295"      "44300"      "44300"      "44300"      "44300"     
 [19] "44300"      "44300"      "44300"      "44300"
```

I have many files, so I cannot work on each file individually. How can I correctly load columns of dates and times from the excel file?

Comment: use `readr` package from `tidyverse`

Comment: I think the issue is because of additional space for the date `24/03/2021`. Does it help if you specify `col_types = 'date'` or `col_types = 'text'` i.e `my_data <- read_excel("file.xlsx", col_types = 'date')`